# ASP - Imprimindo JSON sem ultima virgula e com aspas dupla

Tags: json, asp

Estou precisando fazer uma consulta no banco de dados, e retorna um JSON.

Tentei usar JSON for ASP do Google, mas deu uns erros, então resolvi fazer manualmente:

```
<!--#include file="conexao.asp"-->

<%
medico = replace(request("medico"),"'","")
crm = replace(request("crm"),"'","")

sql = "SELECT nome_pro, crm FROM medicos WHERE nome LIKE UPPER('%" & medico & "%') "
set rs = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")
rs.cursorlocation = 3
rs.open sql,conexao


response.write("[")
If Not RS.EOF Then
Do
    response.write("{")
    for each x in rs.fields

        response.write("'" & x.name & "'")
        response.write(":")
        response.write("'" & x.value & "'")
        response.write(",") 

    next
    response.write("}")
    response.write(",")
    RS.MoveNext()

Loop Until RS.EOF
End If   
response.write("]")
%>
```

O problema que estou tendo, é que quando ele imprime o JSON, sai a ultima virgula, assim:

[{'NOME_PRO':'ALCINDO','CRM':'000000',},{'NOME_PRO':'PEDRO ','CRM':'000000',},{'NOME_PRO':'PEDRO','CRM':'111111',},]

Nunca usei ASP, estou usando pela primeiravez pra gerar esse JSON, e queria saber se tem algum metodo de não imprimir essa ultima virgula.

E tambem queria saber se tem como fazer com que o:

```
response.write("'" & x.name & "'")
```

Imprima aspas duplas em vez de imprimir unica.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de escrever diretamente, armazene o resultado em uma variável, e no final do processo, remova a virgula no final e depois escreva o resultado.

Veja:

```
<!--#include file="conexao.asp"-->

<%
medico = replace(request("medico"),"'","")
crm = replace(request("crm"),"'","")

sql = "SELECT nome_pro, crm FROM medicos WHERE nome LIKE UPPER('%" & medico & "%') "
set rs = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")
rs.cursorlocation = 3
rs.open sql,conexao

Dim resposta

resposta = "["

If Not RS.EOF Then
Do
    resposta = resposta & "{"

    for each x in rs.fields

        resposta = resposta & "'" & x.name & "'"
        resposta = resposta & ":"
        resposta = resposta & "'" & x.value & "'"
        resposta = resposta & ","

    next

    resposta = resposta & "}"
    resposta = resposta & ","

    RS.MoveNext()

Loop Until RS.EOF
End If   

'Aqui removemos a ultima virgula no final da string.'
resposta = Left(resposta, (len(resposta)-1))

resposta = resposta & "]"

response.write resposta
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vou mostrar somente o techo do loop, pois é somente nesse trecho que modifiquei:

```
c2 = 0;
Do
    If c2 > 0 Then
        response.write(",")
    End If
    response.write("{")
    c = 0;
    for each x in rs.fields
        If c > 0 Then
            response.write(",")
        End If
        response.write("'" & x.name & "'")
        response.write(":")
        response.write("'" & x.value & "'")
        c = 1
    next
    response.write("}")
    c2 = 1;
    RS.MoveNext()
Loop Until RS.EOF
```

A lógica é adicionar a vírgula antes e permitir somente quando o contador for maior que 0, ou seja, quando o laço de repetição estiver rodando o segundo registro em diante.

Note que existe o contador **c2** e **c**.

O **c2** é para o loop primário.

Dentro do loop primário há outro loop, onde usei uma variável chamada **c**.

O importante é iniciar os contadores com valor 0 antes de iniciar cada loop, não dentro do loop.

Também cuidado com caracteres reservados do json. É mais seguro escapar as strings caso contenham caracteres reservados como double quote, por exemplo.

```
Replace(str, ""","\"")
```

Exemplo prático

```
response.write("'" & Replace(x.name, ""","\"") & "'")
```